# 1 board, 2 chickens,3 baskets 9 positions

Tags: identify-this-game

Small ceramic board,2 chickens,9 positions,3 nests; 2 nests with 2 eggs & one nest with one egg. Eggs non removeable. Can I send a photo?

Comment: Upload your photo to a hosting site like Imgur, edit the share link into the question, and if the software doesn't do it automatically, one of the mods will turn that into an inline image.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to B&CG Stack Exchange!  You can [edit] your question to add the photo and anything else you can recall about the game (any details of play, for instance).  If you haven't already, you should also take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] to help clarify how Stack Exchange works.